# How to tell syllables apart

Tags: hangul

I’ve just started to learn Korean, so I might be asking something that’s obvious... but I sometimes struggle how to do syllabication when it comes to writing. For example ‘kakyeok’ I thought would be as ‘kak-yeok’ but it’s ‘ka-kyeok’. So this: 가격 is the correct way of writing it, but I wrote it as 각역. Is there a rule for this? Or does the syllabication get easier the more you learn? Grateful for any tips!

Answer (score 3):

Most of all, you should avoid using romanizations to learn Korean words. I have seen a lot of non-standard and even wrong romanizations on the Web, which may mislead most beginners. The standard one for 가격 is [gagyeok](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%EA%B0%80%EA%B2%A9) *not* kakyeok, and the correct pronunciation is ka̠ɡjʌ̹k̚ in IPA.

The spelling 각역 is also correct for the same romanization. 각역 (meaning carving, engraving, etc.) is hardly used in daily conversation, but it does not mean that 각역 is the wrong answer. The consonant ㅇ here indicates that the character starts with a vowel sound (You should also note that ㅇ is the consonant pronounced as ŋ when it is placed at the bottom of a character). Thus, 각역 is pronounced as 가격; I mean, both 가격 and 각역 sound the same. *When two words sound the same, their romanizations have to be the same* (although there are exceptions regarding tensification and the consonant ㅎ). There should be the **context** that determines the spelling.

If you learn more, you will notice that the phrase 각 역 (meaning each station, each role, etc.) is also correct. Some people pronounce it as 강녁 (강녁 is also the pronunciation of 강력), others pronounce it as 각 역 (with a short pause), and the others pronounce it as 가격. For this phrase, *however*, most people will write the standard romanization as *gak yeok* because of the space between 각 and 역. It shows that the real pronunciation of a word or pharse is *not always* relevant to the romanization.